# If $A\subseteq C$ then $AB\cap C=A(B\cap C)$?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, algebraic-number-theory

$A,B,C$ can be anything (e.g. I proved it for Galois extensions of $\Bbb Q$).  Can someone find a proof or a counterexample (for any class of $A,B,C$, e.g. groups, rings) that if $A\subseteq C$ then $AB\cap C\subseteq A(B\cap C)$?  (since the $\supseteq$ is obvious).

My proof is really really long, by induction on the power of prime factors dividing $[B:B\cap C]$; however, I'm pretty sure I've seen an elementary proof back in high school (which obviously wasn't in the context of Galois extensions).

EDIT: AB is the compositum of A and B.

Comment: what does $AB$ mean?

Comment: The set of all $\Sigma a_ib_i$, where $a_i\in A, b_i\in B$.  I pondered over whether I should include this in the post, but then decided this is pretty standard in group/field/ring theory.  :)

Comment: I think it would be better defined to be the compositum, which is actually defined for groups and other things.

Comment: I mean, I thought what I said is precisely the meaning of the compositum?

Comment: In general, the description you gave for $AB$ is not a field, even if $A$ and $B$ are fields.  However, the compositum $AB$ is a field.

Comment: @Alex Only for unital rings and algebraic field extensions.  The definition of the compositum of $A$ and $B$ should be "the smallest thing containing both $A$ and $B$", which takes different forms in different cases.

Comment: A not-too-relevant observation: the identity (with the **product**, not compositum) does not hold for ideals: in $\Bbb Z$ $$(2)((3)\cap (6))=(12)\\ (2)(3)\cap (6)=(6)\\ :)$$

Comment: @Slade Oh, thank you.  I guess I usually only work with groups / rings/ algebraic field extensions; so I did not realize that it's different for other objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $A(B\cap C) \subset AB\cap AC$, but the reverse containment will only hold if the lattice of subobjects is distributive.  For subfields of a Galois extension, this will happen only if the Galois group is [locally cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_cyclic_group).

You are asking about the case where $A\subset C$, equivalently $AC=C$.  This case is equivalent to the lattice of subobjects being [modular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice), which is a more subtle condition.

But there are Galois groups with non-modular subgroup lattices, notably $D_8$.  So we have the following counterexample for finite extensions of fields, arising from the splitting field of $X^4-2$:

$A = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}], B=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{-2}], C=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]$.  Then $AB\cap C = C$, but $A(B\cap C) = A$.

However, the case where all the extensions are Galois follows from the general fact that the lattice of normal subgroups of a group is modular, which is an elementary result.

Comment: The assumption was that $A\subseteq C$.  Thanks for your useful comments, though.  :)

Comment: @Alex I think it is fixed, and addresses your question now.

Comment: But, in this example $B$ and $C$ themselves are not Galois over any common field...

Comment: @Alex My point is that we cannot expect this equation to hold for _general_ $A,B,C$, not even for finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.  When they are Galois over a common field, then there is no counterexample, because the equation is true—we can use the Galois correspondence and the fact that the lattice of normal subgroups is modular to arrive at an elementary proof in that case.

Comment: @Alex Similarly, your equation holds for normal subgroups of a group, but not for general subgroups of a group.

Comment: OK, thank you.  This is the information I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify but I shall assume that $A,B,C$ are substructures of some structure $M$ such that $\def\wi{\subseteq}$$A \wi C$, and that "$ST$" denotes the structure generated by (finite combinations from) $S,T$ for any $S,T \wi M$.
$\def\qq{\mathbb{Q}}$
$\def\gen#1{\langle#1\rangle}$

Then obviously $A(B \cap C) \wi AB \cap C$, because every element in $A(B \cap C)$ is in $AB$ and $AC = C$ by definition of generation.

The reverse containment does not hold, at least for groups. Let $A = \gen{(1,2,3,4,5)}$ (generated by this 5-cycle) and $B = \gen{(1,2)}$ (generated by this swap) and $C = A_5$ (alternating group on $\{1..5\}$). Then $A(B \cap C) = A\gen{} = A$ but $AB \cap C = S_5 \cap C = C$.